# Broke ng-class by using a factory

Tags: angularjs, factory, ng-class

I had ng-class working great with everything defined on the controller $scope:

```
<body ng-app="thomasApp" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <nav hide-show-nav ng-class="{'fixed-nav':fixedNav, 'hide-nav':!showNav}">
   <ul>...</ul>
  </nav>
  ...
</body>

app.controller("AppCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.showNav = true;
  $scope.fixedNav = false;

  $scope.toggleNav = function() {
    $scope.showNav = !$scope.showNav;
  }
  ...
});
```

But I haven't been able to get it working after switching to a factory:

```
<body ng-app="thomasApp" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <nav hide-show-nav ng-class="{'fixed-nav':nav.fixed, 'hide-nav':!nav.show}">
   <ul>...</ul>
  </nav>
  ...
</body>

app.controller("AppCtrl", function($scope, nav) {
  $scope.nav = nav;
)};

app.factory("nav", function($rootScope) {
  var nav,
      show = true,
      fixed = false;

  nav = {
    show: show,

    fixed: fixed,

    toggleShow: function() {
      nav.show = !nav.show;
    }
    ...
  };

  return nav;
});
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/5XqDL/2/

I watched the nav object in console.log, and the nav.show and nav.fixed variables are changing where they are supposed to. It's just that the classes are not being applied.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the changes to `nav` are made outside of the Angular context (from the event listener callback for window's `scroll` event), you need to manually call `scope.$apply()` at the end of the callback.

```
.bind('scroll', function (evt) {
    ...
    scope.$apply();
});
```

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/5XqDL/4/)**.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The event is supposed to be triggered when the user scrolls below 400px, as should be reflected in the fiddle.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned the directive. It's in the fiddle. Was working fine with the controller definitions...

Comment: I got it (finally). Check my updated answer. (There is still work to be done on the design part, though.)

Comment: Thanks again. I'm sure you're right, I'm new to both angular and javascript. The idea is to make the nav detach at 400px and become a drop down on certain events.

Comment: I am sure you'll work out the functionality stuff. If this answer solved the `ng-class` problem, please mark it as accepted. (Upvotes are welcome ss well :))

Comment: Can't check it out till later, but yes absolutely will.